# Python 3 - Is it legal to grant external access to the 'self' variable from within the constructor?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to do something like this in Python 3:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, values):
        if some_condition:
            init_from_values(self, values)
```

Is this legal?  That is, can I pass the 'self' variable to another code block prior to exiting the constructor?

Comment: If you *couldn't* access `self` from a constructor, the constructor would be completely unable to do its job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that's fine. You can have constructors delegate work to other functions. Just make sure that the other code doesn't do things that assume the object is fully-constructed; for example, don't call methods that you permit subclasses to override, unless the subclass methods know what to do with a partially-constructed `self`.